# What is the definition of a variety in Mumford's red book?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, definition, schemes

In Mumford's red book, prevariety is defined (in II.3) as follows:

> If $k$ is an algebraically closed field, a prevariety over $k$ is a reduced and irreducible prescheme of finite type over $k$.

Mumford then starts mentioning variety later on and I wasn't sure what it was exactly. I can not seem to find the definition in the book. Any clarification is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Definition 2, in section I.6 in the second edition.

Comment: In that definition of variety, prevariety is the 'old' definition from Chapter I. We are supposed to replace that with the scheme theoretic definition of prevariety to get the 'new' definition of variety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the book, definition 2 in chapter I section 6 in the second edition (pg 37):

> **Definition 2 (Chapter I section 6, pg 37)**. Let $X$ be a prevariety. $X$ is a *variety* if for all prevarieties $Y$ and for all morphisms $$f,g:Y\rightrightarrows X$$ $\{y\in Y\mid f(y)=g(y)\}$ is a closed subset of $Y$.

The next proposition explains things a little:

> **Proposition 4 (Chapter I section 6, pg 37)**. Let $X$ be a prevariety. Then $X$ is a variety if and only if $\Delta(X)$ is closed in $X\times X$.

In chapter II, we have the same thing happening with schemes and preschemes:

> **Definition 2** (Chapter II section 6, pg 118): $f(x)\equiv g(x)$ if $f\circ i_x=g\circ i_x$, where $i_x:\operatorname{Spec} k(x)\to K$ is the canonical morphism. Equivalently, this means that $f(x)=g(x)$, and that the 2 maps $f^*_x,g^*_x:k(f(x))\to k(x)$ are equal.

> **Proposition 4** (Chapter II section 6, pg 118): For all $f,g:K\to X$, $$\{x\in k\mid f(x)\equiv g(x)\}$$ is locally closed.

> **Definition 3** (Chapter II section 6, pg 118): A prescheme $X$ is a *scheme* if for all preschemes $K$ and all $K$-valued points $f,g$ of $X$, $\{x\in K\mid f(x)\equiv g(x)\}$ is closed.

> **Proposition 5** (Chapter II section 6, pg 118): If $X$ is a prescheme over a ring $R$, then the criterion for $X$ to be a scheme is satisfied for all $K,f,g$ if it is satisfied in the case: $K=X\times_{\operatorname{Spec} R} X$, $f=p_1$, $g=p_2$.

> **Corollary 1** (Chapter II section 6, pg 119): If $k$ is an algebraically closed field, then a prevariety over $k$ is a variety in the sense of Ch. I if and only if it is a scheme.

In the modern language, this is the statement that $X$ is separated. So for Mumford, a variety is a separated prevariety. You'll find some other examples of this in older literature (use of pre-variety or pre-scheme to denote a possibly nonseparated variety or scheme), but this language has been out of fashion for many, many years.

Comment: This makes it very clear, thank you!